# class cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, jsp, types, comparator

I want to write a compare class so that I can sort a list of elements using this comparator later on, but i get an error.
The code looks as such:

```
class Elem {
            public String user_name;
            public String given_name;


            public String getGivenName() {
                return given_name;
            }
        }

        class Compare implements Comparator<Elem> {
            public int compare(Elem o1, Elem o2) {
                return o1.getGivenName().compareTo(o2.getGivenName());
            }
        }
```

This gives me the error:

> Elem cannot be resolved to a type

I'm not sure how I can fix this error.

Comment: Is the file structure as you depicted above? Please append package declaration and imports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the compiler cannot find class `Elem`.

Don't forget to import it at the top of your java class in case the `Elem` class is in the different package.

Also make sure you don't have any typo.

Answer (score 1):

The code above compiles cleanly at my machine (Java 7) with the added import.

```
import java.util.Comparator;

class Elem {
    public String user_name;
    public String given_name;


    public String getGivenName() {
        return given_name;
    }
}

class Compare implements Comparator<Elem> {
    public int compare(Elem o1, Elem o2) {
        return o1.getGivenName().compareTo(o2.getGivenName());
    }

}
```